# dropdownlist error object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a DropDownList which is shown below:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="moduleInfo" runat="server" DataSourceID="currentModules" class="table table-striped table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  GridLines="None">
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="module" ItemStyle-Width="30"  >
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="entryLevel" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Level 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Level 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Level 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Level 4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Level 5" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

When I try to reference it in the code behind it was not recognized by typing `entryLevel`, so i used below code:

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)moduleInfo.FindControl("entryLevel");
string Level = ddl.SelectedValue;
```

Whenever I run the web-page and select the value, I get the error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

Anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: The dropdown is inside item template - this means there will be many such dropdowns. Which one of them are you expecting to get as `FindControl` result?

Comment: i want to get use FindControl to get the dropdown "entryLevel"

Comment: There are many of them - one for each row in the gridview.

Comment: Where did you bind the dropdownlist? did not see it in your code

Comment: @cred Where did you place that server-side code? Could you show the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `Rows` class of GridView to get the exact DropDownList replace below line:

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)moduleInfo.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("entryLevel");
```

And if you are using your code in RowCommand event then you can get `rowIndex` as like this:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
```